# The quotes that cover the string disappear C++

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I try to cover the string with quotes in order to I can put it into the SQL record

```
int pictureId = picture.getId();
std::string pictureName = "\'" + picture.getName() + "\'";
std::string picturePath = "\'" + picture.getPath() + "\'";
std::string pictureCreationTime = "\'" + picture.getCreationDate() + "\'";

std::string TRY = "Insert Into Pictures(Id, Name, Location, Creation_Date, 
Album_id) Values(" + std::to_string(picture.getId()) + ',' + 
picture.getName() + "," + picture.getPath() + ',' + 
picture.getCreationDate() + ',' + '1' + ");";

res = sqlite3_exec(db, TRY.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, &errMessage);
```

After the line

```
std::string TRY = "Insert Into Pictures(Id, Name, Location, Creation_Date, 
Album_id) Values(" + std::to_string(picture.getId()) + ',' + 
picture.getName() + "," + picture.getPath() + ',' + 
picture.getCreationDate() + ',' + '1' + ");";
```

The quotes are disappear
What can I do in order to the quotes will not disappear

Comment: You're asking for SQL injections. Don't escape your strings, ask your database library to do it for you, for instance with parametrized requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes disappear becuse on the line that you say causes problems you use picture.getName() instead of using the pictureName string you created with the single quotes.

```
int pictureId = picture.getId();
std::string pictureName = "\'" + picture.getName() + "\'";
std::string picturePath = "\'" + picture.getPath() + "\'";
std::string pictureCreationTime = "\'" + picture.getCreationDate() + "\'";

std::string TRY = "Insert Into Pictures(Id, Name, Location, Creation_Date, 
Album_id) Values(" + std::to_string(pictureId ) + ',' + 
pictureName  + "," + picturePath + ',' + 
pictureCreationTime + ',' + '1' + ");";
```

Comment: Thanks You. 
I do not understand how I didn't notice.